# Unable to fetch scores list in Flox for AIR Android

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework, leaderboard

When I use the code from the Flox documentation:

```
import com.gamua.flox.Flox;
import com.gamua.flox.Player;
import com.gamua.flox.Score;
import com.gamua.flox.TimeScope;

Flox.loadScores("top-scores", TimeScope.ALL_TIME, 
    function onComplete(scores:Array):void {
    trace("retrieved " + scores.length + " scores");
    for each (var score:Score in scores)
        trace(score.playerName, score.value);
},
function onError(error:String):void {
    trace("error loading scores: " + error);
}
    );
}
```

I get the following error:
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Score.

Why am I getting this error??

Comment: I hope you've pointed the path to the classes? There's no other proper explanation (except missing the file or having it with a wrong class name)..

Comment: I am using a SWC file.. I am successfully able to use all other Flox methods without any error.

Comment: Try to inspect the swc to see what classes/methods are there. It seems like the class is missing :) Try rewrite the path - maybe you put some special character somewhere?

Comment: I've rechecked everything many time, but the error doesn't seem to go away. I really don't get it. Anyways, I was able to make to make it work by using a simple for loop.. Thanks for the answers... I appreciate them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the code work by using a for-loop. If anyone else is having the problem, do following:

```
Flox.loadScores("top-scores", TimeScope.ALL_TIME, 
    function onComplete(scores:Array):void {
    trace("retrieved " + scores.length + " scores");
    for(var i:int = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
    {
        trace(scores[i].playerName, scores[i].playerId, scores[i].value);
    }
    },
    function onError(error:String):void {
        trace("error loading scores: " + error);
    }
        );
```